# Wordpress php redirect by custom url

Tags: wordpress, redirect

I have additional url like app1.mydomain.com point to the home page (mydomain.com), but I want to when people enter url app1.mydomain.com it will redirect to specific page.

- I only know how to redirect 1 page to another but not a custom url to 1 specific page. Please help me if you have advice, do I have to modify it in .htaccess ? can it be done by php?

Comment: You can create a 301 redirect in your htaccess -

Comment: Yes, I really do, because it's hard for me to contact to the people who manage the server unless it is impossible?

Comment: I did similar thing with WP plugin - you can redirect your custom page to another page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this in your .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond "%{HTTP_HOST}"   "!^app1\.mydomain\.com" [NC]
RewriteRule "^/?(.*)"        "http://app.mydomain.com/$1" [L,R]
```

Or if you want to redirect ALL requests done on that domain, regardless from the requested path, to a specific page you can use:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond "%{HTTP_HOST}"   "!^app1\.mydomain\.com" [NC]
RewriteRule "^.*$"           "http://app.mydomain.com/thispage" [L,R]
```

Comment: Thanks for quick reply, 

I actually want to redirect app1.mydomain.com to mydomain.com/thispage 

not the home page anymore, should I put this on .htaccess?

Comment: @pexichdu I edited my answer with the relevant information.

Comment: It does redirect but  it not only apply to app1.mydomain.com but also my home page (mydomain.com) & any link that pointing to home page also. I only want to apply to app1.mydomain.com, is there anything  I did wrong? Also can I use this same syntax multiple time?

Comment: @pexichdu did you write the RewriteCond correctly? Are you maybe on HTTPS? Could you post your actual .htaccess in use?